# How to solve error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Tags: java, android

This code used to work but I added some things just to get the contentprovider name[s].  No matter how much I check that there wont be any null or empty arraylists, it still does the same error.

LogCat

```
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600): Process: com.example.sillimaninquirer, PID: 11600
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at com.example.sillimaninquirer.Adapter.getView(NewsFeed.java:402)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2467)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1286)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1194)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1692)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:760)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:846)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:512)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:447)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5698)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:465)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2728)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17915)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2412)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1414)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1638)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1292)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6598)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:800)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:786)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
05-25 08:57:40.429: E/AndroidRuntime(11600):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

NewsFeed.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.androidquery.AQuery;
import com.androidquery.callback.AjaxCallback;
import com.androidquery.callback.AjaxStatus;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NewsFeed extends Activity {
    ListView feed_listView;
    EditText search;
    //Button t, a, d, c, k;
    Spinner spinner;

    AQuery aq;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    Adapter artadapter;
    JSONArray articles          = new JSONArray();
    ArrayList<String> artID     = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    ArrayList<String> title     = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    ArrayList<String> content   = new ArrayList<String>();  
    ArrayList<String> date      = new ArrayList<String>();  
    ArrayList<String> cpid      = new ArrayList<String>();  
    ArrayList<String> publisher         = new ArrayList<String>();  

    JSONArray contentprovider           = new JSONArray();
    ArrayList<String> cpID  = new ArrayList<String>();   

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_feed);
        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        aq = new AQuery(this);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setMessage("Loading articles. . .");
        pd.setCancelable(false);

        getSIData();
        getContentProvider();
        search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

        feed_listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_NewsFeed);


        artadapter = new Adapter(this,artID, title, content, date, publisher,cpid);
        feed_listView.setAdapter(artadapter);

        feed_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                String t = title.get(position);
                String c = content.get(position);
                String d = date.get(position);
                String p = publisher.get(position);
                String cp = cpid.get(position);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Article.class);
                i.putExtra("t", t);
                i.putExtra("c", c);
                i.putExtra("d", d);
                i.putExtra("p", p);
                i.putExtra("cp", cp);
                startActivity(i);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }           
        });
        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    searchTitle(s.toString());
                    if(s.toString().equals("")){
                        clearVar();
                        addArticlesToVar();
                    }

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

            }
        });

    }
    public void AddPref(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), AddPreference.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    public void News(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), NewsFeed.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.news_feed, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void getSIData(){
        aq.progress(pd).ajax("http://sillimaninquirer.esy.es/TWS/sidata.php?key=none", JSONObject.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>(){
            @Override
            public void callback(String url, JSONObject jo, AjaxStatus as){
                try {
                    if(jo!=null){
                        articles = jo.getJSONArray("articles");
                        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Articles: "+articles, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error: No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                addArticlesToVar();
            }
        });
    }
    public void getContentProvider(){
        aq.progress(pd).ajax("http://sillimaninquirer.esy.es/TWS/sidata.php?key=contentprovider", JSONObject.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>(){
            @Override
            public void callback(String url, JSONObject jo, AjaxStatus as){
                try {
                    if(jo!=null){
                        contentprovider = jo.getJSONArray("contentprovider");
                        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Articles: "+articles, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error: No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public void addArticlesToVar(){
        // articles = Manage.getArticles();
         for(int x=0; x<articles.length(); x++){
             try {
                JSONObject article = articles.getJSONObject(x);
                artID.add(article.getString("id"));
                title.add(article.getString("title"));
                content.add(article.getString("content"));
                date.add(article.getString("pdate"));
                String pub = article.getString("pubid");
                if(pub=="1"){
                    publisher.add("Stones and Pebbles");
                }
                if(pub=="1"){
                    publisher.add("Junior Sillimanians");
                }
                if(pub=="1"){
                    publisher.add("the Weekly Sillimanian");
                }
                String a = article.getString("cpid");
                for(int y=0; y<contentprovider.length(); y++){
                     try {
                        JSONObject cp = contentprovider.getJSONObject(y);
                        String con = article.getString("id");
                        if(a==con){
                            String fname = cp.getString("firstname");
                            String lname = cp.getString("lastname");
                            String mi = cp.getString("mi");
                            cpid.add(fname+" "+mi+". "+lname);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException r) {
                        r.printStackTrace();
                    }
                 }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
         artadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         Log.d("XX"," has art? "+articles);
     }
    public void searchTitle(String key){
        clearVar();
        for(int x=0; x<articles.length(); x++){
             try {

                JSONObject article = articles.getJSONObject(x);
                    String[] splited   = article.getString("title").split(" "); //split on word boundries
                    if(Arrays.asList(splited).contains(key)){
                        artID.add(article.getString("id"));
                        title.add(article.getString("title"));
                        content.add(article.getString("content"));
                        date.add(article.getString("pdate"));
                        String pub = article.getString("pubid");
                        if(pub=="1"){
                            publisher.add("Stones and Pebbles");
                        }
                        if(pub=="1"){
                            publisher.add("Junior Sillimanians");
                        }
                        if(pub=="1"){
                            publisher.add("the Weekly Sillimanian");
                        }
                        String a = article.getString("cpid");
                        for(int y=0; y<contentprovider.length(); y++){
                             try {
                                JSONObject cp = contentprovider.getJSONObject(y);
                                String con = article.getString("id");
                                if(a==con){
                                    String fname = cp.getString("firstname");
                                    String lname = cp.getString("lastname");
                                    String mi = cp.getString("mi");
                                    cpid.add(fname+" "+mi+". "+lname);
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                         }
                    }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
        artadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void searchDate(String key){
        clearVar();
        for(int x=0; x<articles.length(); x++){
             try {

                JSONObject article = articles.getJSONObject(x);
                String[] splited   = article.getString("pdtae").split(" "); //split on word boundries
                if(Arrays.asList(splited).contains(key)){
                    artID.add(article.getString("id"));
                    title.add(article.getString("title"));
                    content.add(article.getString("content"));
                    date.add(article.getString("pdate"));
                    String pub = article.getString("pubid");
                    if(pub=="1"){
                        publisher.add("Stones and Pebbles");
                    }
                    if(pub=="1"){
                        publisher.add("Junior Sillimanians");
                    }
                    if(pub=="1"){
                        publisher.add("the Weekly Sillimanian");
                    }
                    String a = article.getString("cpid");
                    for(int y=0; y<contentprovider.length(); y++){
                         try {
                            JSONObject cp = contentprovider.getJSONObject(y);
                            String con = article.getString("id");
                            if(a==con){
                                String fname = cp.getString("firstname");
                                String lname = cp.getString("lastname");
                                String mi = cp.getString("mi");
                                cpid.add(fname+" "+mi+". "+lname);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                     }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
        artadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void clearVar(){
        title.clear();
        content.clear();
        date.clear();
        cpid.clear();
    }
}
class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> artID, title, content, date, apubid, cpid;
    //ArrayList<Articles> art1, art2;

    Adapter (Context context, ArrayList<String> artID,ArrayList<String> title,ArrayList<String> content, ArrayList<String> date, ArrayList<String> apubid, ArrayList<String>cpid){

        super(context, R.layout.row,R.id.newsfeed_Title, title);
        this.context = context;
        this.artID  = artID;
        this.content  = content;
        this.date     = date;
        this.title    = title;
        this.apubid = apubid;
        this.cpid     = cpid;

    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        String c="", con="";
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        TextView tv_title   = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.newsfeed_Title);
        TextView tv_content = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.newsfeed_Contentext);
        TextView tv_date    = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.newsfeed_date);


        c = content.get(position);
        for(int cc=0; cc<50; cc++){
            con+=c.charAt(cc);
        }

        tv_title.setText(title.get(position));
        tv_content.setText(apubid.get(position)+"\n"+con);
        tv_date.setText("By "+cpid.get(position)+"   "+date.get(position));

        return row;


    }

}
```

Comment: You're trying to get the first item out of an ArrayList that contains **no** items. Check the variables on the line that throws the exception.

Answer (score 0):

when you call

```
 artadapter = new Adapter(this,artID, title, content, date, publisher,cpid);
```

the content array is empty. This is why you get the problem